# Preventing ArcMap layout view re-drawing every time label moved etc?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, layouts

In the Layout View whenever I move graphics, or labels within it, ArcMap  10.1 redraws it.

How do I turn that off to prevent it from re-drawing repeatedly?

Answer (score 2):

To stop a data frame redrawing go to the **Frame** tab of its **Properties** and tick the check box at the bottom for **Draft Mode**.

[image]

Then in **Layout View** that Data Frame will appear simply as a grey rectangle with the Data Frame name on it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure these options are what you're looking for, but hopefully one or more will be useful.

It's possible to [pause the drawing of the map](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Pausing_the_map_s_drawing/006600000011000000/) in data or layout view by clicking the pause button at the bottom left of the data frame, but it's designed more for when you're changing a layer's symbology or properties, not working directly in the map or layout. The topic has a note about pausing label drawing as well.

You might want to look at some topics referenced in the [improving map display performance](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Tips_on_improving_map_display_performance/006600000400000000/). I've linked to the first one which is an overview. It mentions analyzing a map document and using caching to improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

Optimized map/layer rendering may help as mkennedy has suggested, however most layout design decisions (moving elements, creating elements) do not directly involve the viewing the data.  I usually just turn all layers off while configuring these elements (right click on data frame name and select **Turn All Layers Off** option).

Answer (score -1):

Another solution is to press F9 for pause ON/OFF.